# Is the unreduced Burau representation completely reducible?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, braid-groups

To be specific, my question is about specializations $\beta \colon B_n \to GL_\text{n}\left( \mathbb C \right)$ of the unreduced Burau representation given by
\begin{array}{cr}
\beta \left( \sigma_{i} \right)= I_{i-1}\oplus\begin{pmatrix}
1-z & z \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\oplus I_{n-i-1} & 1\leq i\leq{n-1},~z\in \mathbb C^{*}
\end{array}
where $B_n$ is the braid group on n strands and $\{\sigma_1,...,\sigma_{n-1}\}$ are the standard generators.

Is this representation completely reducible or not?

I think that the answer is no, but I can't find an argument to prove it. I'm first and foremost interested in just knowing the answer, and where to find a reference of it. Secondly I would like to be able to prove it, if possible without use of homological arguments and the definition of the braid group as a mapping class group, as I'm not altogether very familiar with that theory.

In the book "Braid groups" by Kassel and Turaev it is shown that in a suitable basis the representation can be written as
\begin{array}{c}
\beta ( \sigma_{i} )=\begin{pmatrix}
\hat{\beta} (\sigma_{i}) & 0 \\
\star_{i} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{array}
where $\hat{\beta}$ is the reduced Burau representation and $\star_{i}$ is a row of length $n-1$ equal to zero if $i=1,...,n-2$ and equal to $(0,...,0,1)$ if $i=n-1$. Also, $n$ should be greater than or equal to $3$.

It also says in the book that "the Burau representation can be reduced but is not a direct sum of its reduced form with a one-dimensional representation", but I'm unsure whether it is meant that this is true in general, or if it's somehow specific for the case above. In either case, I'm looking for a proof showing that $\beta$ is, or is not, completely reducible.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n=2$, the braid group $B_n$ is just the free group on one generator $\sigma$, and the representation is determined by the matrix via which $\sigma$ acts on $\mathbf{C}^2$; for $z=-1$ this is
$$\sigma \mapsto \left( \begin{matrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right). $$ This matrix is conjugate to 
$$\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right),$$ and therefore the representation is not completely reducible: its unique submodule is the (genuine) eigenspace for the eigenvalue $1$, of dimension $1$.

The general fact here is that the quotient of the Burau representation by the span of the all $1$'s vector is also known as the Specht module (indexed by the partition $(n-1,1,0,\dots,0)$, deforming the reflection representation) for the finite Hecke algebra of $S_n$ . This is irreducible unless the parameter $z$ is a non-trivial $n$th root of $1$, in which case it is reducible and it is not semisimple.

This material is covered for instance in Andrew Mathas' book here

http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=ULECT-15

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Specht module, but since the unreduced Burau representation is reducible for any value of z, I don't see how it could be the same as the Burau representation. Could you explain more on how this is connected to my question?

Comment: @steinbrenner  Er, sorry, you're right---it's a deformation of the permutation representation of $S_n$, and it's not the Specht module for the partition I wrote. I'll fix that. In any case, as you can see in the $n=2$ example, it's not completely reducible.

Comment: With the changes this makes a lot more sense. I have two thoughts however: (1) For z=1 the representation is unitary and hence completely reducible, how does this fit into the picture? (2) As I understand it, this shows that span{(1,...,1)} is invariant but does not have an invariant complement. But how can I be sure that there isn't some other invariant subspace (possibly with some other dimension) that has an invariant complement?

Comment: For (1), when $z=1$ the representation factors through the group algebra of the symmetric group (this is the case I meant to exclude by writing "non-trivial $n$th root of $1$"), and every representation of a group algebra is semi-simple (in characteristic $0$).

Comment: For (2), the detailed part of my answer shows that the unique simple submodule in the $n=2$ case is the span of the vector $(1,1)^t$: any submodule must contain an eigenvector for $\sigma$.

Comment: @steinbrenner, for question (2) in the case of general $n>2$, you could reason as follows: if a modulle has a quotient that is not semisimple, then it is not semisimple. Then look in Mathas' book.